# Android - Display all data from from sqlite in a tabular form

Tags: android, textview, android-sqlite

So below is my code that i use to display sqlite data in a single textview.
So far so good. But now i need the the data to be in a Tabular form. I need the "billprint" String, because i am using it for printing the details in a printing device.

So, is there any way that the details can be printed/displayed in a tabular form within a single string file.?

```
private void displaydb() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    billprint = "";
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;

    try {
        myDB = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("shopcart1", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM tbl_cartitems";
        Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("productID");
        int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("productName");
        int Column3 = c.getColumnIndex("productQuantity");
        int Column4 = c.getColumnIndex("productPrice");

        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c != null) {
            do {
                String pID = c.getString(Column1);
                String pName = c.getString(Column2);
                String pQua = c.getString(Column3);
                String pPri = c.getString(Column4);


                billprint = billprint +""+
                        pID+"   "+pName+"       "+""+pQua+"  "+pPri+"\n";
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        tv.setText(pppid);
        tv.setTextSize(18F);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Database Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        if (myDB != null)
            myDB.close();
    }
}
```

So far the output is in this form:

```
prod-1 vanilla ice cream 1 15
prod-2 chocolate ice cream 5 50
prod-3 milk ice cream 10 150
```

But the output that i want should be in tabular form like:

```
prod-1 vanilla ice cream    1   15
prod-2 chocolate ice cream  5   50
prod-3 milk ice cream       10  150
```

layout (activity_testing.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.naji.productorder.Testing" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your ViewGroup is Linearlayout,then set the weight to all your textview, or create your Textview dynamically and add proper LayoutParams.

Comment: Sorry i cant do that, i just need the string file to be able to display data in tabular form, since i will be using this string to print in a device by retrieving data from database dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this kind of coding standard.

- you should separate Ui component and Db operation by splitting up in separate class.
- Use AsyncTask for Db operation,and create DTO class to hold data to be stored after fetching from sqlite
- separate your business logic in service class.
  Don't do all operation in single class.

Comment: You have to format it by using \n,\r and spaces("").

Comment: Actually i don't use this way for any database operation. I have seperate DBHelper class for database operation. i just gave the method to let people understand my situation. I just need a correct output for the string file. And \n or \t doesnt help, since the product name is variable hence, it goes out of sync.

Comment: You have to split the row into n number.(n=no of columns).For each column ,you should fix its maximum length.For each product name,its size is less than the fixed length,add spaces.(no of spaces added=fixed length-length of the product).By this way you can do this.I did it the same

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit. May be an example. I have been stuck in this for 2 days. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a WebView instead of TextView to display. Because if you can. This code can ease your task.

```
WebView webView;
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    String billprint = "<table>";
    if (c != null) {
        do {

            String pID = c.getString(Column1);
            String pName = c.getString(Column2);
            String pQua = c.getString(Column3);
            String pPri = c.getString(Column4);

            billprint += "<tr>"
                + "<td>prod-"+pID+"</td>"
                + "<td>"+pName+"</td>"
                + "<td>"+pQua+"</td>"
                + "<td>"+pPri+"</td>"
                + "</tr>";
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    billprint += "</table>";

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, billprint, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Through WebView i can display it in tabular form. But i need a string file. I will be using that string for printing the output in a device printer.

Comment: Ok. I got your problem. Just to let you know that you can print webview's content also in a device printer. Even you can create a pdf from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
int i=0;
String billprint="";
String billprint1="";

List<String[]> billprint2= new ArrayList<>();

String fff[];


String pID1[] = {"data1","data2","data3"};
String pName1[] =  {"wwwwwww","eeee","qqqqqq"};
String pQua1[] =  {"1","2","3"};
String pPri1[] =  {"12","13","14"};
do {
    String pID = pID1[i];
    String pName = pName1[i];
    String pQua = pQua1[i];
    String pPri = pPri1[i];


    billprint = billprint +""+
            pID+"   "+pName+"       "+""+pQua+"  "+pPri+"\n";
    ;
    String[] b1 = new String[] {pID,pName,pQua,pPri};
    Log.e("DATA",""+b1);
    billprint2.add(b1);

    i++;
} while (i<3);


String data2[];
int maxLemgth=0;
for(String sde[]: billprint2){
    data2 = sde;
    for(int y =0 ;y<data2.length;y++){
        Log.e("DATA",""+data2[y]);

        if(maxLemgth<data2[y].length())
            maxLemgth = data2[y].length();
    }
}

String HoldData="";
int counter =1;
// find data length and add space
for(String sde[]: billprint2){
    data2 = sde;

    for(int y =0 ;y<data2.length;y++){
        Log.e("DATA",""+data2[y]);

            int checklength = data2[y].length();
            if(maxLemgth>=checklength){
                String addSpace = addSpace(data2[y],(maxLemgth-checklength)+1);
                HoldData = HoldData+addSpace;
            }
            else{
                HoldData = HoldData+data2[y];

        }


    }

    HoldData=HoldData+"\n";

    counter++;
}

Log.e("DATA",""+HoldData);
```

and

```
public String addSpace(String Data, int spacecount){

        if(spacecount>0) {
            for (int d = 0; d < spacecount; d++) {
                Data = Data + " ";
            }
        }

        return Data;
    }
```

**output:**

```
E/DATA: 

data1   wwwwwww 1       12      

data2   eeee    2       13      

data3   qqqqqq  3       14
```

I hope this will help you.. thanks

Comment: Thanks this method works for Sytem.out.print and in log. But when i try to implement this in a textview or even in my printer, in both cases, it again goes out of order. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: I have added the layout.

Comment: OK... Change width ...wrap_content to fill_parent and and same as linear layout... Match to fill

Comment: And take weight=1 into textview

Answer (score 0):

If you use a monospaced font you can use java formatter to allocate N (16 in this case) characters per item.

Doesn't work for proportional fonts since they vary in width.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);

    String s1 = "foo";
    String s2 = "bar";
    String s3 = "foobar";
    String s4 = "hubba bubba";

    formatter.format("%16s %16s %16s %16s\n", s1, s2, s3, s4);
    formatter.format("%16s %16s %16s %16s\n", s4, s3, s2, s1);

    System.out.print(formatter);
```